# Displaying a dynamic KML file on Google Maps as it is on Google Earth

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-earth, kml-network-link

how can i display my kml files through network link on Google Maps instead of showing it on Google Earth.

I have tried the step mentioned on this link

https://developers.google.com/kml/articles/pagesforkml

but stucked at step 3 where it is saying for uploading kml file as no option is available there.

Actually ,I'm uploading KML maps because , my KML file size is more than 2 MB and as i refresh it on google earth , it got hanged..

So what i need is a network link on Google maps which will show my my.kml file placemarks and this network link is having a refresh interval time ..my.kml file is generating at every 10 seconds by a java program...

my network link code is :
   // pasted only the network link part

```
<NetworkLink>
<Link>
<href>/home/placeMarkers.kml</href>
<refreshmode>onChange</refreshmode>
<refreshInterval>60</refreshInterval>
<viewRefreshMode>onStop</viewRefreshMode>
<viewRefreshTime>20</viewRefreshTime>
 </Link>
</NetworkLink>
</kml>
```

Comment: You expect the user to reload 2MB file every 10 seconds?

Comment: i expect the file to be refresh in every n seconds automatically and that part i have done , but when it is about to refresh Google earth get hang

Comment: I meant - 720Mb/hour seems like a lot...

Comment: ok...putting it very simply...how should i code in network link which will refresh my.kml file in every 10 seconds...instead of doing in through Google earth - properties - refresh - timebased refresh...i have edit my question showing the code of network link

Comment: Don't get me wrong but "refreshing" results in data download. That is what BradHards mentioned.

Comment: Network KML is NOT FULLY supported on Google Maps - Only Google Earth - see https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/GDyfinWu9-U "We don't support many KML features - refreshMode is one of them." {Google Employee}

Comment: @Mapperz whenever i run my above mentioned network link , my kml file gets loaded , but after n seconds either it get hanged or dnt get refresh .. previously i used to get it trough Google Earth -timebased refresh ...but now whenever i do it gets hang....how should i hardcode it properly !!

Comment: kindly assist ..how should i move forward...also see my edit part whether network link will work or not

Comment: You could use the google maps API and link it to a KML which you update. See here for an example - www.2northstreet.com/seismic.html